# Simple SVN post-commit hook for Jenkins on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, jenkins, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server holding several repos with PHP applications on Windows Server 2008 machine.

I need to figure out how to deploy PHP scripts to production machines (2 Windows servers + 1 Linux/Apache), preferably NOT by setting local repos on them. I tried to use Jenkins but I'm having a hard time figuring out how SVN-Jenkins communication works.

I need a script that would be executed every time a commit is made and deploy only modified files to the production servers. Can someone suggest a solution, please?